# ExpressionEngine and CORS?

Tags: htaccess, security

I need to enable cross-domain AJAX requests on my site, while limiting the cross-domain access to a particular template.

This template is in its own template group, so the requests from the script would look something like this:

```
domain.com/embeddable-content
```

I have this in my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

But this grants access across the entire domain. How would I go about restricting access to the single template?

I've googled around, but this is slightly out of my bailiwick, and I figure there my be complications because of EE's file structure (or lack thereof).

Comment: FYI, if anyone is interested, here's an ExpressionEngine plugin for adding the CORS header: https://github.com/alistapart/comment-embed/tree/master/third_party

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're only allowing access to a single template, I'd imagine the easiest way would be to use PHP's header to add

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

At the top of the template

Comment: That is, of course, very sensible. I was stuck in .htaccess thinking.

Comment: This works — but not once the template has been cached. The PHP header isn't being sent again. Any thoughts on how to overcome that?

Comment: You can either disable caching on the template (not sure what you're using to cache it right now), or have the user append a unix timestamp on their api request, making it always unique?

I'm fairly new to EE still -- there may be a better method that's EE specific.

Comment: Native caching wasn't sending the headers, but I turned on CE Cache (something I've been meaning to do anyway) and now the headers are being sent correctly.

Comment: @DaveDeHaan I have a similar situation and tried to implement your line, but still getting the same message. `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/submissions. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: Make sure that the header is in PHP, and is before all other content on the page?  Hard to guess past that.

Comment: Well... Is first on the template page, but EE might be putting things before it.

Comment: EE's 301 on .htaccess to remove the www was my problem. Directed the call to the address with no www. and it worked :)

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do this in htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/index.php/embeddable-content(/.*)?" CORS=TRUE
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=CORS
</IfModule>
```

This'll only set the CORS header when your request matches that URI.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to enable PHP in your templates you can also use https://github.com/nathanpitman/np_access_control_allow_origin.pi.ee_addon to do this. :)